# Laravel 5.5 - Pivot tables and hasMany relationship

Tags: php, laravel

Let's say I have this following. 4 tables and 3 models (Role, Posts, Users).

[image]

A `User` can be assigned many `Roles` and `Roles` can be assigned to many `Users`.

`Posts` can created with one `Role` per entry in the database.

**What I need help with**

I want to be able to grab a list of all posts of a user from their associated roles. So by calling `auth()->user()->getPosts()`, I should get all `Posts` from `Roles` that are attached to a `User`. I thought I could use `hasManyThrough` but I don't see it can help my case as I get: `SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'roles.user_id' in 'field list' (SQL: select`posts`.*,`roles`.`user_id`from`posts`inner join`roles`on`roles`.`id`=`posts`.`role_id`where`roles`.`user_id`= 1)`

Here are my models thus far:

**User.php**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    public function roles()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Role::class);
    }

    public function posts()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough(Posts::class, Role::class);
    }
}
```

**Role.php**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Role extends Model
{
    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class);
    }
}
```

**Posts.php**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Posts extends Model
{
    public function roles()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Role::class);
    }
}
```

Clone this problem here: https://github.com/naknode/eloquent-help

Comment: Here is a git repo of where I am currently at. https://github.com/naknode/eloquent-help

Comment: Are your table names `users,roles` or `user, role` ?

Comment: No they are as outlined in the graph. `users`, `posts`, `user_role` and `roles`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forget about `hasManyThrough`, I was wrong.

Here how you can do it:

```
    $user = User::with('roles')->first();

    $userPosts = Posts::whereIn('role_id', $user->roles->pluck('id')->toArray())->get();

    return $userPosts;
```

If you want to get the posts by calling `auth()->user()->getPosts()` add the following method to your User model:

```
public function getPosts()
{
    return Posts::whereIn('role_id', $this->roles->pluck('id')->toArray())->get();
}
```

Comment: Well how about that. Thank you so much. I understand it finally. The roles associated from the user in the pivot table are used as an array and obtained to get the posts.